# How do you average Ki values?

Tags: pharmacology, terminology

It's embarrassing for me to ask this but well such is life. [NIMH Psychoactive Drug Screening Program (PDSP) Ki Database](http://pdsp.med.unc.edu/pdsp.php?) is mentioned as the source of the average binding affinity (K<sub>i</sub>) values given in [Goodman and Gilman](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071624422) but whenever I try to, in some way, confirm that these values are averages obtained from PDSP I get values that are way (up to 10,000 fold) off the values given in Goodman and Gilman. (ps. I am a mathematician too so I know how to take an average, $\bar{x} = \frac{\sum_i^n x_i}{n}$ so you don't need to hold my hand through the calculation with something as simple as the conventional definition of averages) Therefore I have reached the conclusion that I must be doing the calculations wrong. Please show me how to do them correctly. Here's a screenshot of exactly what Goodman and Gilman says that's confusing me:

[image]
[image]

Oh and yes I am using just the cloned human transporter values not just all the stuff that comes up.

Comment: check the units.. may be a μM to nM conversion problem.. verify

Comment: Nope, all the units are nM.

Comment: it would be better if you can save this page as a document or pdf and put it in dropbox. Or if there is an ebook then please provide the url if it is possible.

Comment: The latter would be a breach of copyright and the other I don't quite understand how that would be better.

Comment: Sharing the URL: if it is open such as in the books in the NCBI site. Better: so that i dont need to zoom in to see.

Answer (score 1):

Since I asked this question I found out what I was doing wrong in searching for K<sub>i</sub> (i.e. I thought the K<sub>i</sub> ID was the *test ligand* and hence I was searching for drugs the wrong way) values but also how, **I think** Goodman and Gilman got its K<sub>i</sub> values.

I think what they did was they searched for the **hot ligand** that gave the most **consistent** and **numerous** K<sub>i</sub> values and took the average of the consistent K<sub>i</sub> values (with an relative tolerance of ~100% between results). Additionally since I knew the data, as is stated in the page displayed above, was taken 30 June 2009 I was able to eliminate some sources that were probably not available on PDSP at the time. Using this I was able to get consistent averaged K<sub>i</sub> values in the vast majority of cases (with like, at most a small handful of exceptions).